# Split string into rows and columns

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have one long enormous string:

```
mystr <- "foo   one   undefined + foo   two   undefined + BAR   three   undefined + "
```

And I want to turn it into

```
   x1    x2        x3
1 foo   one undefined
2 foo   two undefined
3 bar three undefined
```

By using the `+` to create new rows, then spaces to create columns. Is this possible? I tried using str_split and mutate but I couldn't seem to figure out how to create new rows. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `read.table` after replacing the `+` with `\n` using `gsub` in `base R`

```
read.table(text = gsub("+", "\n", mystr, fixed = TRUE),
       header = FALSE, col.names = paste0('x', 1:3))
#    x1    x2        x3
#1 foo   one undefined
#2 foo   two undefined
#3 BAR three undefined
```

Or using `strsplit` with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = strsplit(mystr, " + ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]], header = FALSE)
```

---

Or we can use `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(text = gsub("+", "\n", mystr, fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = mystr) %>% 
   separate_rows(col1, sep="\\s*\\+\\s*") %>%
   separate(col1, into = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')) %>%
   na.omit
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  x1    x2    x3       
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>    
#1 foo   one   undefined
#2 foo   two   undefined
#3 BAR   three undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Base R solution:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", sapply(strsplit(trimws(mystr, "both"), "\\+"), 
        function(x){strsplit(trimws(x, "both"), "\\s+")})))
```